# Перенос VirtueMart c одного домена на другой.

Tags: virtuemart, joomla, php

Доброго времени суток. дело вот какое: нам нужно перенести  VirtueMart с одного домена на другой.
Однако при переносе возникла проблема, а именно - сайт встал на место, магазин работает (но частично) - когда открываешь магазин - список категорий магазина показывает, а когда жмешь на категорию - что бы просмотреть товары внутри - то переводит на прежний сайт. 
Выглядит это где-то так:
ССС.com -> ccc.com/shop
(Нажимаем на категорию и переводит на старый сайт)
zzz.com/shop/cat3
а должно было перевести 
CCC.com/shop/cat3.

Целый день сегодня вожусь и не могу понять как это исправить. 
Читал на разных сайтах там говорят править вот так:
http://www.treeone.ru/stati/201-pravilnyj-perenos-virtuemart-na-khosting
Однако не получается никак.
По их инструкции выходит:
http://zzz.comccc.comindex.php/?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=120&Itemid=2
Тоесть получается что как бы объединяются два url адреса.

Как перенести правильно магазин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, хочешь что-то сделать - сделай сам. Выгрузил весь сайт к себе на комп (15000 файлов), открыл поиском от notepad++ и просканировал все файлы. Нашел порядка 30 совпадений. Заменил все на нужный урл - все заработало! Если будет у Вас такая же проблема - можете использовать мой метод - удачи!

Comment: 30 совпадений с доменом? не может такого быть, в конфиге вирты прописывается путь в 2-3 местах не более.